# When does the first subgroup growth function grow?

Tags: gr.group-theory

Given a group $G$, the *subgroup growth functions* are given by

> $a_n(G) :=$ the number of subgroups of $G$ of index exactly $n$.
>
> $s_n(G) :=$ the number of subgroups of $G$ of index at most $n$.

The latter is clearly increasing. I wonder when the sequence $a_n(G)$ enjoys similar behavior.

To be specific, say a sequence $\{ x_n \}_{n=1}^\infty$ is *roughly increasing* if there exists $C > 1$ such that $x_{C n} \geq x_n$ for all natural numbers $n$.

> **Question**: For what groups $G$ is $a_n(G)$ roughly increasing? In particular, is $a_n(G)$ roughly increasing for $G = SL_3(\mathbb{Z})$?

Note that the sequence $a_n(G)$ is roughly increasing for any finitely generated nilpotent $G$ that is infinite. On the other hand, the sequence $a_n(G)$ is never roughly increasing for finite $G$.

Comment: Does this not follow from the rather precise estimates for $a_n$ obtained by Lubotzky--Nikolov (https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2155033) for arithmetic groups with CSP? (I'm asking before doing the computation to see if you tried yourself).

Comment: Thank you for your reply and for thinking about my question. The main challenge to applying their work is that they only control the growth of $\log(s_n)$.

Comment: You're right, I assumed they dealt with $a_n$ but I was mistaken. Do you know if their proof or that of Goldfeld--Pyber--Lubotzky at least implies that $a_n \ge 1$ for sufficiently large $n$?

Comment: I believe the answer to Jean Raimbault's question is no, since  there seems to be infinitely many $n$ where $a_n(G) = 0$ for $G = SL_3(\mathbb{Z})$. For this, apply Guralnick's theorem from his J. Algebra paper "Subgroups of Prime Power Index in a Simple Group" to show that for sufficiently large p and k, $a_{p^k}(G) = 0$. Note this doesn't show that $a_n(G)$ is not roughly increasing.

Comment: My gut feeling is that $a_n(SL_3(\mathbb{Z}))$ ought to be roughly increasing. If one takes $C$ to be an index in which a lot of finite-index subgroups of index $C$ in $SL_3(\mathbb{Z})$ exist, then intersecting these with subgroups of index $n$, I would expect "most" to have maximal index, i.e. $Cn$.

Comment: My guess is that for free groups the sequence is roughly increasing. The growth is so fast that it makes sense. However, to prove it one has to look at what we know and see how precise it is.

Comment: I would also guess that for infinite pro-$p$ groups (at least those which are non-$p$-adic analytic) the growth is also roughly increasing. Does anyone have a counter example?

Comment: For free groups $a_n$ is actually increasing. The same thing holds for surface groups (these are two cases where there are asymptotic equivalents for $a_n$ that grow very fast). In some cases (Fuchsian groups, RAAGs, RACGs) there are estimates for $a_n$, which are sufficient to prove that it is roughly increasing. In fact I think any finitely generated group which surjects onto $F_2$ should have $a_n$ roughly increasing. But this is the opposite situation to $SL_3(\mathbb Z)$.